# Understanding chain complexes of vector spaces over a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

I'm trying to understand this section of Weibel's *An Introduction Homological Algebra*, Section 1.4.

[image]

First of all, is it just a general fact about vector spaces that whenever $V=A\oplus B$, then $B\simeq V/A$? I'm also confused about why kernel of $ds+sd$ is $H_n'$. And then in the next line, it says the kernel of $ds+sd$ is the trivial homology complex.

Also still don't get why the condition $d=dsd$ has to do with the notion of a complex being *split*.

I'm new to this and I'd appreciate it if someone could flesh out the details.

Comment: For your first question, suppose you have a linear map $T:V \mapsto W$, then by the kernel rank theorem, we have $V \cong \text{ker}(T) \oplus\text{im}(T)$. It is also true, than $\text{im}(T) \cong T / \text{ker}(T)$ (think first isomorphism theorem).

Comment: In terms of short exact sequences, look at $0\mapsto Z_{n} \mapsto C_{n} \xrightarrow{d} B'_{n} \mapsto 0$, and for vector spaces, any short exact sequence is split exact, so $0 \mapsto C_{n} \cong Z_{n} \oplus B'_{n} \mapsto 0$. The second sequence is $B_{n} \rightarrow Z_{n} \xrightarrow{\pi} H_{n}(C_{\bullet})$.

Comment: As for your second question, if you "plug in" the second equation into the first, you get that $C_{n} \cong B_{n} \oplus  H'_{n} \oplus B'_{n} \cong B_{n} \oplus B'_{n} \oplus H'_{n}$ (where the second isomorphism is $(a,b,c) \mapsto (a,c,b)$. Now $ds+sd$ maps surjectively onto the first two entries of $C_{n}$, that is $B_{n} \oplus B'_{n}$, so the kernel is isomorphic to $H'_{n}$. (look at my first comment)

Comment: what is your definition of a chain complex being split? in some sense,  the existence of $s_{n} : C_{n} \mapsto C_{n+1}$ such that $d=dsd$ is the definition of a chain complex being split.